# Suggestion on Power supply design

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, capacitive

I am looking for Transformerless power supply design. I have MCU 5V. and would like to drive 12V/24V relay with single LED.
i have 4 pots 10K/200k for timing
So i prefer 230VAC to 12V/24Vdc output with min 0.5A current.[5v 500mA](https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/on-semiconductor/mc79m05cdtg/on-semiconductor-5-v-linear-voltage-regulator/5164941?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIi-yKvojL5wIVzLWWCh1TnwtiEAQYASABEgKzM_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[Power supply](https://www.google.com/search?q=capacitive%20power%20supply&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN818IN818&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFvcScicvnAhXT4zgGHU_DC7YQ_AUoAnoECA4QBA&biw=1242&bih=568)

Comment: Suggest that  you purchase a switching supply, such as a reasonable quality 5V USB phone charger, before you hurt yourself.

Comment: That is a negative 5 volt linear regulator that you linked, but your MCU uses positive 5 volts (presumably).

Comment: Wow, @Jasen just deleted his answer just as I was posting a comment to ask what justification there was to say that a 500mA transformerless power supply would not work.

Comment: Why do you think you need a transformerless power supply? Also note that a capacitive dropper supply provides no isolation from mains and is dangerous for that reason (among others).

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work. 500mA is way too much to ask of a transformerless supply.

Use a phone charger for your 5V and find a 5V relay, or if you must use a boost converter to make 12V.